# When I execute following code it give me above error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return sumValBinding }" Message: sumValBinding is not defined
```

Here my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputdefault">First number</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="Textbox1" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputdefault">Second number</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="Textbox2" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputdefault">Answer</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="TextboxSum" type="number" data-bind="value:sumValBinding">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

==============================================================================
Here Javascript/Knockout JS`enter code here`

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Textbox1").value);
        number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Textbox2").value);
        sumOfTwoNumber = number1 + number2;
        console.log(parseInt(number2));
        //v = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), document.getElementById("TextboxSum"));
    });
    var viewModel = function()
    {
        sumValBinding: ko.observable(sumOfTwoNumber) // Prepopulate
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model is a constructor function therefore, you should assign a property to this if you wish to have it in an object instance:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    this.sumValBinding = ko.observable(sumOfTwoNumber);
};
```

or your constructor can return an object:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    return {
       sumValBinding: ko.observable(sumOfTwoNumber);
    };
};
```